# Node.js won't load css at a specific url path length

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, webpack

When I try to load my css on a page with the follow path:

`http://wwww.example.com/test` = works!

`http://www.example.com/test/test` = works!

`http://www.example.com/test/test/test` = **doesn't work!**

I'm using NodeJS, ExpressJS and ReactJS.
My dev server doesn't have this problem, it only occurs on the production server. Maybe it has something to do with the dev dependencies?

This is the folder structure so far.

[image]

My server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const port = 80;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started and is listening on port ', port);
```

index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stadro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/style/global/error.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/style/global/global.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/style/webapp/dashboard.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/style/webapp/content.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/style/webapp/hubbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/style/webapp/navbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/style/website/contact.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/style/website/support.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/style/website/header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/style/website/about.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body class="webapp-style">
    <div class="webapp"></div>
</body>
<script src="/dist/app/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js file

```
var path = require('path');

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");

var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

var config = {
    entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/",
    output: {
       path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
       filename: "bundle.js",
       publicPath: "/app/"
   },
   module: {
       loaders: [
           {
               test: /\.js?/,         
               include: SRC_DIR,      
               loader: "babel-loader",
               query: {
                   presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
               }
           }
       ]
   },
   devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,    
        port:8080
   }
};

module.exports = config;
```

**SOLUTION:**
Thanks @taco, I changed the `<link>` href paths to start at the top level.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stadro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/style/global/error.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/style/global/global.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/style/webapp/dashboard.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/style/webapp/content.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/style/webapp/hubbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/style/webapp/navbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/style/website/contact.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/style/website/support.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/style/website/header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/style/website/about.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body class="webapp-style">
    <div class="webapp"></div>
</body>
<script src="/dist/app/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: does console shows any erros when you navigate to http://www.example.com/test/test/

Comment: @FadiAboMsalam , I don't see any errors. When I navigate to example.com/test/test/

Comment: so inspect the page and check the head does you css links show there if so click on the url of the css does it load

Comment: the head shows the css paths and when I click on it, it redirects me to the right file. But if the path is wrong (example above) than there's nothing in the css files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the `src` attributes to start at the top level

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/{fullpathtocssfile}">
```

The easiest way to determine what path to use is to test from shell.

`cd app`

`find . -name 'error.css'`

Then use the path it for the `href` source.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Added the solution to the post above!